# What is mergeDrawableStates()?

Tags: android

While working with `stateListDrawable`, I can't help but notice that to switch state you override the `onCreateDrawableState()` and you have to use `mergeDrawableStates(...)` within it.

So my question is what exactly does [`mergeDrawableStates(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#mergeDrawableStates(int[],%20int[])) do? I checked the android documentation on it already and the explanation currently makes absolutely no sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

As you must be knowing that `onCreateDrawableState()` method call is requested by `refreshDrawableState()` method. Whenever we want to refresh drawable state of a view,`refreshDrawableState()` call is needed.

So lets come to the point that what `mergeDrawableStates()` method do.

This method adds the new states to already available states. So it is used to create custom view states. If you want to create custom states, you need to pass two parameters. One is an integer array of already available `states` (`drawableState` check following snippet) and another one is an integer array of custom `states` (`STATE_MESSAGE_UNREAD` check following snippet). As a result it adds new state array to the array of already available states that is passed as first parameter (`drawableState`) which in tern is being returned from `onCreateDrawableState()` method definition.

Lets have a look at an implementation:

```
@Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        // If the message is unread then we merge our custom message unread state into
        // the existing drawable state before returning it.
        if (messageUnread) {
            // We are going to add 1 extra state.
            final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);

            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_MESSAGE_UNREAD);
            return drawableState;
        } else {
            return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
        }
    }
```

So when you call `mergeDrawableStates()` your view knows about new states that will be used when you change view state to new custom state.

To check full implementation [visit this](http://charlesharley.com/2012/programming/custom-drawable-states-in-android)